# Getting Error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities for firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using : 
java:1.8
Selenium: 3.141.59 jar
Geco driver version: 0.25.0
Firefox version : 69.0.1

Below is the executable.bat file detail:

```
start java -jar C:/eclipse-workspace/Selenium_Grid/Config/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub

start java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:/Selenium/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe -jar C:/eclipse-workspace/Selenium_Grid/Config/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -maxSession 5 -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=10 

start java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=D:/Selenium/geckodriver-v0.25.0-win64/geckodriver.exe -jar C:/eclipse-workspace/Selenium_Grid/Config/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5559 -maxSession 5
```

[Configuration of Grid Hub and node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlTvy.png)

Below is the code :

```java
public static RemoteWebDriver getBrowserDriver(final String browser)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),
            getBrowserCapabilities(browser));
}

private static DesiredCapabilities getBrowserCapabilities(
        final String browserType) throws MalformedURLException {
    switch (browserType.toLowerCase()) {
    case "firefox":
        System.out.println("Opening firefox driver");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);       
        return capabilities;
    }
}
```

On running code getting below exception log :

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, marionette: true, platform: WIN10, version: }
>   Command duration or timeout: 801 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
>   System info: host: 'GP-PIN-IS04', ip: '192.168.250.72', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
>   Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>   Caused by: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox,

Comment: Please edit your question, and add a screenshot of the Grid console so that we know what is the browser flavors that are getting registered (dont forget to switch to the `configuration` tab of the grid console, when taking the screenshot)

Comment: Thank Krishnan for response, I have attached screen shot as guided, please let me know if anything else needed from my end.

Comment: Update : Issue was resolved by after Firefox update version : 69.0.2, also on using firefoxoptions and merging the capabilities, below is the example :DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
              capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
              FirefoxOptions options= new FirefoxOptions();
              options.merge(capabilities);

Answer (score 1):

So your error says "Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities"  which means it is looking for a node that matches the capabilities you asked for when creating the remote driver, but it cannot find one. In the line that is starting your geckodriver, you are not specifying a browser like you are for the chrome one.  Probably it would be easier to create a node config file and pass it in when starting the node like this:

```
java -Dwebdirver.gecko.driver="D:/Selenium/geckodriver-v0.25.0-win64/geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node -hub "http://localhost:4444/grid/register/" -port 5559 -nodeConfig config.json
```

Here is what the config file for your firefox node could look like:

```
 {
 "capabilities": [
   {
     "browserName": "firefox",
     "platform": "WIN10",
     "maxInstances": 5
   }      
 ],
 "hub": "http://<hub ip>:<hub port>"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Shannon for reply, but still getting the same error even after using config way.

Comment: Maybe try updating your grid jar? Looks like you are using a pretty old one.

Comment: I am using 3.141.59 selenium server jar,also gecko driver 0.25.0 version, if these are the older one kindly guide me to latest jar download link.

Comment: Hi Keshav, here is a link to download the latest grid jars.  I am using 3.8.1 but they have also come out with Selenium 4  http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html